# Web Development Guidelines for Xbox One Browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I'm developing a *website* which needs to be accessible via the Xbox One browser, but can't find any information anywhere about web content guidelines or development specifications, requirements, or whatever. I'm not even sure which browser Xbox One uses. IE? Edge? Likewise, I can't even find contact information to reach out to them.

I know PS4 released [this document](http://www.sie.com/content/dam/corporate/jp/guideline/PS4_Web_Content-Guidelines_e.pdf) a while ago, which states the limitations of its browser. Is there similar documentation for Xbox One? Additionally, is there more extensive information for PS4?

Can anybody provide any information about any of this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xbox One's browser runs a modified version of Internet Explorer 10.

[**This article**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn532261(v=vs.85).aspx) by Microsoft has a fairly comprehensive list of the differences between IE 10 and XBOX One's browser.

It's also worth noting that XBOX One **can** be made to run Edge, as is pointed out in this [**SitePoint article**](https://www.sitepoint.com/debugging-html5-xbox-one-ms-edge-xbox-windows-store-app-vorlon-js/).

Simply develop for those two browsers and you should be fine.

Some general development tips for XBOX One, taken from Microsoft:

- Design for mouse, keyboard, touch, and controller
- Design for 1024px width
- Use adaptive design
  CSS Media Queries or JavaScript can be used to change the layout of your page based on properties of the device that is loading the page.
  On mobile devices, consider reducing image quality to save bandwidth and improve performance.
- Minimize horizontal scrolling on narrow devices to improve readability
- Avoid using plug-ins
- Use HTML5 audio and video (H.264/AAC/MP3)
- Avoid using pop-up windows

JavaScript debugging can be achieved by checking for the `Xbox One` user agent:

```
if (/Xbox One/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    XBoxOne = true;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: i also came across videos of people using edge on xbox one. so this spruced up version of IE is default?

Comment: The spruced up version of IE 10 **is** the built-in Xbox One browser. You can run Edge as an independent app :)

Comment: Definitely helpful. Tyvm <3

Answer (score 1):

Xbox one browser is internet explorer minus a few html 5 capabilities... Maybe this is what your looking for? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn532261(v=vs.85).aspx

You can use the gamepad api to handle controller events

xbox handles voice commands by scanning your webpage for interactive elements and adding them to Microsoft's speech recognition engine.

Keep your webpage relatively simple as recommended by Microsoft and avoid using drag-and-drop, hover, and timed interactions.

To maximize availability consider TV, PC, tablet, mobile screens

Users cannot copy and paste

w3c Geolocation services are not available

Happy developing!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16902630)

Comment: Thank you for the helpful comment, edited my response

Comment: also, i think it's important to note that it's not a spruced up version of internet explorer, but rather internet explorer 10 minus a few HTML5 features.

Comment: Ok I changed it, the reason I used 'spruced up' is because of built in voice recognition capabilities, the gaming api to handle controller events, 'cursor gravity', and gesture recognition. I think xboxOne IE probably adds more capabilities than removes